# Batch file Menu program closes unexpectedly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I started coding 2 days ago, and wanted to make a menu based program where you type input to prompts.

Somehow, after line 14, the program closes, and I have no clue why.

It would be awesome if someone could explain why my code doesn't work, instead of posting completely new code!

````
echo off
:c
color fa
echo ====================================
echo =      WELCOME!I AM LIZA!          =
echo =      HOW ARE YOU TODAY?          =
echo =    1) Im great :D                =
echo =    2) Im okay :I                 =
echo =    3) Im sad :(                  =
echo =                                  =
echo ====================================
echo.
echo.
set /p ans="Enter your number to continue:"

if %ans%==1(
goto a1
)
if %ans%==2(
goto a2
)
if %ans%==3(
goto a3
)

:a1
cls
echo Liza: Nice to hear so! :D What did you do today?
echo.
set /p ans=">> "
cls
echo Liza: Sounds awesome! I was swimming in millions of bits today, it was so fun! xD
pause

:a2
cls
echo Liza: You dont seem like... What happened that makes you feel unconfy? ;(
echo.
set /p ans=">> "
cls
echo Liza: Im sorry for that, I hope talking to me makes it better tho ;)
pause

:a3
cls
echo Liza: Why so?! Tell me what or who makes you sad, im here for you to cheer you up!
echo.
set /p ans=">> "
cls
echo Liza: Oh my god, thats terrible im so sorry for you! I hope you feel better after talking to me, because im a software that is just nice :D
pause
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific issue, is that you have failed to include a space character immediately before the opening parentheses.

incorrect:

```
if %ans%==1(
```

correct:

```
if %ans%==1 (
```

more correct:

```
if "%ans%" == "1" (
```

However, you should replace your entire `:c` labelled section to use the more appropriate command, like this:

```
Color FA
Echo ====================================
Echo =      WELCOME!I AM LIZA!          =
Echo =      HOW ARE YOU TODAY?          =
Echo =    1) Im great :D                =
Echo =    2) Im okay :I                 =
Echo =    3) Im sad :(                  =
Echo =                                  =
Echo ====================================
Echo(
Echo(
Choice /C 123 /N /M "Enter your number to continue:"
GoTo a%ErrorLevel%
```

Comment: I would also advise, as you appear to be intent on exclaiming everything unnecessarily, that you begin your script with `@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`, instead of `echo off`. Currently with delayed expansion enabled, accidentally or otherwise, your exclamation points, `!` could be removed, or worse still, things like: `Echo =      WELCOME!I AM LIZA!          =`, would expand to `=      WELCOME          =`. The safest method, especially if you have a need to use delayed expansion anywhere within your script, is of course, to not use exclamation points at all.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! This helped a lot, Im a beginner and this is just all new to me thanks for helping me out! :D